# Not receiving PubNub messages when the user is not actively interacting with any channel

Tags: pubnub

When two clients are subscribed to the same channel, they communicate as expected. However, if I don't perform any kind of activity, such as not sending a new message for an hour, an issue arises. These two old clients can send and receive messages, which is expected. But if I reconnect one of these two old clients or add a new client to the same channel, the old client(s) that were created in the beginning do not receive messages sent by the new client. However, when an old client sends a message, the new client receives all of those messages.

My Client was created with this configuration:

```
let config = {
    publishKey: pubKey,
    subscribeKey: subKey,
    userId: userId,
    ssl: true,
    presenceTimeout: 300,
    heartbeatInterval: 60,
    heartbeatTimeout: 120,
    keepAlive: true,
    restore: true,
    autoNetworkDetection: true,
    wildcardSubscribe: true,
    leaveOnUnsubscribe: true
};

let client = new PubNub(config);
```

I was subscribing using this:

```
client.subscribe({
    channels: ["myChannelName"],
    timeout: 1200
});
```

I was expecting that the old and new clients should communicate with each other without any issues, as they are connected to the same channel.

But how can I achieve these?

Comment: Swift or JavaScript? Can I ask where you got those code samples?  I'll dig into your issue but really need to know the origin of the code.

Comment: I asked where you got the sample code from because there are some parameters that don't look right and I want to be sure I am looking at the right code and SDK. So which SDK (name and version like Javascript SDK v7.0.5) and where the code came from. Cheers.

Comment: @CraigConover Thanks for your response. But got these parameters from some random examples and from some random SDK's And just I tried my luck.

Comment: @CraigConover I used JS SDk v7.2.2

Comment: Random from where? PN website/docs or third party sites?

Comment: Best path forward is [enable PN JS SDK logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript/troubleshooting) and submit/email to PN Support (support@pubnub.com for investigation.

Comment: And be sure to get your code samples and params from https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript or other PN resources.

Specifically, these params are not something I've seen before (in 9 years):     `wildcardSubscribe: true, leaveOnUnsubscribe: true`